# Book about shape-shifting dragon men and a girl named Summer

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I read this book somewhere between 1997 and 2002; found it in my high school library. The main character was a girl named Summer (I’m pretty sure), but I don’t remember much about the early story. She falls in love with a dragon somewhere along the way, and carries a dragon egg in her bellybutton, I think? And maybe the dragon dies?

Comment: [Dragonborn](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2574397-dragonborn) by Jade Lee? The heroine does carry a dragon egg in her navel (disguised as a jewel) but it was published in 2008 and it's a bit spicy for a high school library!

Comment: It was definitely before 2008, and it wasn’t spicy? A bit of romance between the MCs, but it was for sure high fantasy.

Comment: Definitely not _Dragonborn_ then!

Comment: Although it seems a strange coincidence that in both the girl carries the egg in her navel. Can you remember how the girl manages this in your book? Bellybuttons are pretty small and I would have guessed dragon eggs are pretty big. I couldn't put even a small egg in my belly button without considerable discomfort :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie - Worth posting as an answer, at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*The Unlikely Ones*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/170293) by Mary Brown?

> **The Ring's the thing...**
>
> **Thing** was a young girl who hid beneath a mask. Her companions included a crow, a toad, a goldfish, and a kitten. Never had a more unlikely band of unheroic heroes set off on a difficult and dangerous quest. But Thing had a ring with unusual powers...
>
> **Summer** was an orphan who only wanted to find a husband and settle down. But first she had to help out a blind knight with amnesia and a winged pig. But how to get those two, as well as a raggle-tail assortment of other creatures in distress, to the far-distant place where they belonged? Summer owned almost nothing except a certain magic ring...
>
> **Sophie** was cast adrift in London by the untimely death of her parents. Then an uncle left her a legacy that would lift her up from poverty if she took a dragon's egg into uncharted Asia
>
> [image]

Summer's '*magic ring*' is a red gem that she wears in her navel. It doesn't  give her any significant powers, but it does mean that she doesn't age.

Comment: I would love that insignificant power.

Answer (score 1):

The series is actually called "Pigs Don't Fly", which is also the name of the second book, in which Summer appears. https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/mary-brown/pigs-dont-fly/

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, she appears in the first book and the references to her belly button dragon ring all seem to come from the first book also.

Comment: No, the first book is The Unlikely Ones. All the protagonists (one girl and a load of animals) have jewels embedded in various parts of their anatomy; but the girl is just called "Thing" for most of the book.

Answer (score 0):

***[The Unexpected Dragon](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/198514)*** (1999) by Mary Brown is the book the OP is looking for.

> Includes "Pigs Don't Fly", "Master of Many Treasures", and "Dragonne's Eg".

It is the *[Pigs Don't Fly](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41410-pigs-don-t-fly)* series, it looks like, but *The Unexpected Dragon* seems to have compiled books 2-4 together, and left *The Unlikely Ones* on its own.
This was confusing for me as well, as I owned it, but never knew it was a series pushed together into a single book or had another book to add on to the beginning!

Comment: The word you're looking for is "omnibus".